# Partial matching of strings in lists, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to create some code that will look through the list to see what elements have matches then return those in a new list. I have a function above the determines the two colors for list_b.

```
list_a = ["the red bird is fast", "the blue bird lives in a green tree", "the yellow bird is very angry"]

list_b = ["red", "green"]

list_c = [lambda x: x in list_b, list_a]
```

my desired output in this example is...

```
["the red bird is fast", "the blue bird lives in the green tree"]
```

Comment: `[s for s in list_a if any(c in s for c in list_b)]` if you don't care about word boundaries

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
list_c = [sentence for sentence in list_a if any(color in sentence for color in list_b)]

print(list_c)
```

Output:

```
['the red bird is fast', 'the blue bird lives in a green tree']
```

Read more about list comprehension [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to solve your problem is to use nested loops and the wonderfull "in" keyword.

```
list_a = ["the red bird is fast", "the blue bird lives in a green tree", "the yellow bird is very angry"]
list_b = ["red", "green"]
list_c = []

for color in list_b:
    for sentence in list_a:
        if color in sentence:
            list_c.append(sentence)

print(list_c)
```

Comment: This would return duplicates if more than one keyword occurred in a sentence.

Comment: You're absolutely right and noone sayd that this shouldn't happen.